# Plotting a power fit of for Y=ax^b

Tags: r, function, plot, regression, estimation

I have q list of Weight (Wg) and Total Length (TLcm). I need to plot them and estimate the curve and the "a" and "b" values. 
I tried to do this:

```
f <- function (TLcm,a,b) {a*TLcm^b} 
fit <- nls(Wg~f(TLcm,a,b),start=c(a=0,b=0),data=rel) 
co <- coef(fit) 
curve(WLmodel,add=TRUE,col="red",lwd=2)
```

It did not work because I am not sure if the starting a and b values I am providing are correct. I reach the second step and it stops.

Here is part of my data:

```
>Wg
714
410
465
628
760
1357
900
1023
3750
3600
1000
1200
1100
2750
3100
1500
700
1500
1700
2000

>TLcm
62
50
54
58.5
62
74
65.5
69
104.5
104
70
73
70
91.5
98
80
60
76.5
83
85
```

Sorry i could not put is as table form, but consider Wg is the Y and TLcm is the X. Considering the first values Wg=714g for TLcm=62cm and so on. Thank you for your help.

Comment: (1) Please pay close attention to the formatting edits I made, (2) In the future, don't ask your question again when your original one is put on hold. If you had edited the [first one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22664763/324364), it would have automatically been placed in a review queue to be reopened.

Comment: @joran Shouldn't that be "In the future, `don't` ask ... " ?

Comment: We can't help you much without the data. However, 0 seems like a bad choice as starting values with the power function. Try `start=c(a=1, b=1)`.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Ha! Still a little bleary this morning!

Comment: start=c(a=1, b=1) is not working.... What info do you need in order to help me?

Comment: I can get this to work with "made up" data, so there must be something about your actual data that is causing a problem. Please either (1) post your actual data as an edit to the question, or, upload the data somewhere (Dropbox??) and provide a link.

Comment: I sent you part of my data, i hope it will work. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Don't give initial parameters with `c` but with `list`:

```
> fit <- nls(Wg~a*TLcm^b,data=rel,start=list(a=1,b=1)) 
> fit
Nonlinear regression model
  model: Wg ~ a * TLcm^b
   data: rel
       a        b 
0.002109 3.095466 
 residual sum-of-squares: 140847

Number of iterations to convergence: 31 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 5.658e-07
```

Now you can predict:

```
> plot(rel$TLcm, rel$Wg)
> x <- sort(rel$TLcm)
> lines(x, predict(fit, list(TLcm=x)), col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]